# One asp.net session per application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, session

I save data in HttpContext.Current.Session but when I call my wcf service from different browsers my session have other id and I not find saved data.

How to create session object which have same id for all request to application?

Comment: it's actual common that opening a new instance of your browser, or a different browser, that you cannot pick up your previous session. If you could, then you would be very vulnerable security-wise.

Comment: "How to create session object which have same id for all request to application?" do you really want this or do you want all requests for the same user to do this? There is an `Application` object that can be shared between all requests to an application if that is what you want to be able to do but if you still want it to tell one user from another then you need some way to work out who is who. That is pretty much going to be some custom logic (maybe a custom session provider).

Answer (score 0):

The Session is base on the cookie. So when the cookie change, eg you open the same page from different browser then the session is different.

If you have user logged in, then its up to you to create some common data between the user connection on all connected session.